# Qt, QTextEdit: how do I delete the last character?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I am using a QTextEdit in my C++ GUI application, I use textEdit->append(byteArray); to add some text, unfortunately append() adds a new line character at the end that I would like to remove after each call of append(). I know I could use insertPlainText() which does not add a new line character but it uses a lot more memory when dealing with big documents.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12):

Since the [documentation for `QTextEdit::insertPlainText`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtextedit.html#insertPlainText) says

> It is equivalent to
>
> ```
> edit->textCursor().insertText(text);
> ```

I would assume that you can just do something like

```
edit->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();
```

If you need to you can first clear any selection with

```
edit->textCursor().clearSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Sorry for my question, seems to easy, but I could not find a solution ...